# Converting Windows Path to Linux

Tags: python, regex, linux, windows

I created a CSV file (`driving_log.csv`) for the filepath of each image that my simulator created but I was using my brother's Windows computer when I did that so now the file path looks like this for each image (and there is almost 14000 of them).  I get an error when invoking it from my `file.py`, which is in the same directory as the CSV file.

```
C:\Users\a-ozb\Desktop\onur\behavirol-cloning-carla\IMG\center_2020_02_08_14_16_38_988.jpg,C:\Users\a-ozb\Desktop\onur\behavirol-cloning-carla\IMG\left_2020_02_08_14_16_38_988.jpg,C:\Users\a-ozb\Desktop\onur\behavirol-cloning-carla\IMG\right_2020_02_08_14_16_38_988.jpg,0,0,0,7.918889E-06
```

I'm using Arch Linux.  I want to iterate through each line and change it to this:

```
/home/onur/Documents/behavioral-cloning-CARLA/IMG/center_2020_02_08_14_16_38_988.jpg,left_2020_02_08_14_16_38_988.jpg,right_2020_02_08_14_16_38_988.jpg,0,0,0,7.918889E-06
```

As you can see, I need everything that comes after `\IMG\`.

What is the best way to go about this?  Should I just slice each string at `IMG\` and take what's after it or use regex?

I've tried this for this specific line to see if it works but it doesn't:

```
string = r"C:\Users\a-ozb\Desktop\onur\behavirol-cloning-carla\IMG\center_2020_02_08_14_16_38_988.jpg,C:\Users\a-ozb\Desktop\onur\behavirol-cloning-carla\IMG\left_2020_02_08_14_16_38_988.jpg,C:\Users\a-ozb\Desktop\onur\behavirol-cloning-carla\IMG\right_2020_02_08_14_16_38_988.jpg,0,0,0,7.918889E-06 "

new_string = string.replace(r"'C:\Users\a-ozb\Desktop\onur\behavirol-cloning-carla\IMG\'", r"'/home/onur/Documents/behavioral-cloning-CARLA/IMG/'", 3)

print(new_string)
```

This is the output:

```
C:\Users\a-ozb\Desktop\onur\behavirol-cloning-carla\IMG\center_2020_02_08_14_16_38_988.jpg,C:\Users\a-ozb\Desktop\onur\behavirol-cloning-carla\IMG\left_2020_02_08_14_16_38_988.jpg,C:\Users\a-ozb\Desktop\onur\behavirol-cloning-carla\IMG\right_2020_02_08_14_16_38_988.jpg,0,0,0,7.918889E-06
```

Comment: You may find the standard [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) module helpful for manipulating path.s

Comment: `import ntpath` should give you the Windows version of the `os.path` utilities, even on linux. You could carve up the path from there.

Comment: Take a look at my attempt.

Comment: @tdelaney But I want the linux version of the path and the files like `a-ozb` don't even exist on my computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are running your code on a *nix machine, you can use the [`PureWindowsPath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PureWindowsPath) class:

```
>>> from pathlib import PureWindowsPath, PurePosixPath
>>> path = PureWindowsPath('C:\\Users\\foo\\bar')

>>> path.parts
('c:\\', 'Users', 'foo', 'bar')

>>> PurePosixPath('/usr', *path.parts[2:])
PurePosixPath('/usr/foo/bar')
```

You can apply the string replace method to every line in a text file as follows:

```
with open("input.csv", "r") as f_in:
    with open("output.csv", "w") as f_out:
        for line in f_in:
            new_line = line.replace(...)  # magic goes here
            f_out.write("{}\n".format(new_line))
```

Comment: You don't need to use the `csv` module if you are not after parsing columns. Simply use [`readline()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) to read individual lines as strings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to this party, but I found the following approach to work well:

```
from pathlib import Path, PureWindowsPath

class AgnosticPath(Path):
    """A class that can handle input with Windows (\\) and/or posix (/) separators for paths"""

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        new_path = PureWindowsPath(*args).parts
        if (os.name != "nt") and (len(new_path) > 0) and (new_path[0] in ("/", "\\")):
          new_path = ("/", *new_path[1:])
        return super().__new__(Path, *new_path, **kwargs)
```

To seamlessly apply this to existing code, save it to a separate file and replace `from pathlib import Path` with `from <myfile> import AgnosticPath as Path`